# Flutter background service doesn’t see the new offline data before hot restarting

Tags: flutter, dart, hive, background-process

so I’m using Flutter background service package to upload offline data ( saved using Hive ) to api in the background and it’s working BUT when I add a new offline data and the background function runs it doesn’t see this new data ( like the boxes are open but empty ) but after I hit hot restart it’ll see it and upload it successfully. How can I solve that so it’ll see these data right away after adding them?
Also I made it that when it got uploaded it’ll change a property in this offline data and it got changed when the background function runs but the ui doesn’t get updated unless I also hit hot restart
Do you know what’s the problem here?